# what does &:upcase mean in Ruby

Tags: ruby

A syntax problem about Ruby:

```
p = lambda &:upcase 
p.call('a')    ## A
```

Why it is valid? Where does this 'upcase' come from?
I think there  is not a parameter which should be sent to `upcase`, bug why this proc can have a parameter?

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter is the receiver.

```
lambda(&:upcase)
```

is a shorthand for

```
lambda { |x| x.upcase }
```

just like

```
lambda(&:+)
```

is a shorthand for

```
lambda { |x, y| x.+(y) }
```

More correctly, `&x` in an argument will call `x.to_proc`; `Symbol#to_proc` happens to return the above. For example, this is the definition of `Symbol#to_proc` from Rubinius source:

```
class Symbol
  # Returns a Proc object which respond to the given method by sym.
  def to_proc
    # Put sym in the outer enclosure so that this proc can be instance_eval'd.
    # If we used self in the block and the block is passed to instance_eval, then
    # self becomes the object instance_eval was called on. So to get around this,
    # we leave the symbol in sym and use it in the block.
    #
    sym = self
    Proc.new do |*args, &b|
      raise ArgumentError, "no receiver given" if args.empty?
      args.shift.__send__(sym, *args, &b)
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see, the resultant `Proc` will shift off the first argument to act as receiver, and pass on the rest of the arguments. Thus, `"a"` is the receiver, and the `"a".upcase` thus gets an empty parameter list.